# JavaScript Adding an ID attribute to another created Element

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, setattribute

I have some code here that will do the following. The code creates an element "p" then I append it to a "div" in the HTML. I would like that "p" I just created have an unique identifier (ID) and set the name of the ID. So later on when the user wants to delete the last created element it will be able to get the ID so it can removeChild. Here is the code:

JavaScript:

```
  var $ = function (id)
  {
      return document.getElementById(id);
  }

  function ShowResponse ()
  {
  var myResponse = $("myresponse").value;

  var myPara = document.createElement("p");
  var myDiv = $("mydiv");
  myDiv.appendChild(myPara);

  var myID = document.createElement("id");
  myID.setAttribute("value", ID)

  var myText = document.createTextNode(myResponse);
  myPara.appendChild(myText);
  }

  function RemoveResponse ()
  {

  }

  window.onload = function ()
  {
      $("showresponse").onclick = ShowResponse;
      $("removeresponse").onclick = RemoveResponse;
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <body>
  <div id="mydiv">
  <h1>Practice</h1>

  <p>Hi There</p>
  <p>How are you?</p>

  <p>
<input type="text" id="myresponse">
<br><input type="button" id="showresponse" value="Show Response">
<input type="button" id="removeresponse" value="Remove Response">
  </p>

  <hr>
 </div>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Since id is an attribute don't create an id element, just do this:

```
myPara.setAttribute("id", "id_you_like");
```

Comment: This replaces the existing id if there is one. How do you append an id to an existing id

Comment: @PA-GW You can't. An HTML element can only have one id, since it's used to uniquely identify the element.

Answer (score 72):

You set an element's id by setting its corresponding property:

```
myPara.id = ID;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use dot notation.

```
myPara.id = 'anyNameYouLike';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- Existing content -->
</div>
<button onclick="addNewElement()">Add New Element</button>

<script>
function addNewElement() {
    // Create a new element
    var newElement = document.createElement("div");

    // Set content for the new element
    newElement.textContent = "New element created!";

    // Add an ID attribute to the new element
    newElement.setAttribute("id", "newElementId");

    // Append the new element to the container
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newElement);
}
</script>
```

when the button is clicked, the addNewElement function is called. Inside this function:

A new div element is created using document.createElement("div").
Text content is added to the new element using textContent.
An ID attribute is added to the new element using setAttribute.
Finally, the new element is appended to the container div using appendChild.