# How can I add id="" to a textarea made with javascript?

Tags: javascript, textarea

my textarea is

```
var tex = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
document.body.appendChild(tex);
```

how can I add class and id to the textarea or areas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Adding an ID attribute to another created Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625646/javascript-adding-an-id-attribute-to-another-created-element)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tex = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
tex.setAttribute("class", "democlass");
tex.setAttribute("id", "demoId");
document.body.appendChild(tex);
```

for reference https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp